# How can I refer to two different columns in a COUNTIF function?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif

I have a sheet that looks something like this.

```
       A   |    B         |    C  
1     Age  |   how often  |  occupation 
2     21   |   I don't    |  student  
3     22   |x times a week|  photographer  
4     23   |   etc        |  student  
5     22   |   etc        |  builder  
6     21   |   etc        |  car mechanic  
7     20   |   I don't    |  student
```

I want to track various things, such as the amount of times a student said "I don't".
I'm using google spread sheets at the moment.
How in google spread sheets can I calculate this?

At the moment this is the query I'm using to try to calculate this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum((B2:B7="I don't") * (C2:C7="student")))
```

All results are coming up as zero - cannot seem to get a result. 
If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Have also tried below with no luck.

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B7="I don't",IF(C2:C7="student",1,0)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In google-spreadsheets, as well as in Excel, you can use the `COUNTIFS()` ([Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550), [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)) function:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B7, "I don't", C2:C7, "student")
```

Comment: I changed the first range to B2:B7.

Answer (score 0):

In a google spreadsheet you can also use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=sumproduct(B2:B7="I don't", C2:C7="student")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to present this information, I'll talk to countifs and pivots:

To count the amount of occurrences a text has appeared in a range of cells you'll use a formula like `=COUNTIFS(B2:B7, "I don't", C2:C7, "student")` however, if you're looking to see how many the string "I don't" appears, ie.. "I don't know" or "I don't care for your formula" enter in as an array selecting crtl + Shift + Enter. [How to Count the Occurrences of a Text String](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214153)

But. For your case, which I'm guessing is interpreting the data and drawing comparisons, such as counting students vs builders, age vs occurrences, you're better off using a pivot table. This will pull together all the information and provide an automatic sum or count on the criteria set, quickly drawing comparisons. Google has a great how to guide you can refer off for google sheets [Google Pivot Table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en)